# WiFi and Sound doesn't work on Kali Linux on Mac Mini late 2014

Tags: audio, kali-linux, iwlwifi

I installed Kali Linux on a Mac Mini, but I have problems with the WiFi card, and with sound.

```
~# lspci 
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09))
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57766 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01)
```

Mac Mini late 2014. Built-in audio and WiFi.
Kali 2016.1.
WiFi adapter not recognized.

```
~# iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Sound works only with the internal speaker, even if the external speakers are plugged in.
If I try to change from Internal Audio to Digital Output it doesn't work. (Only these two options are available).
If I try to unplug the speakers and plug them back in, the speakers work while inserting the jack, but when the jack is completely plugged in, it automatically switch to Digital Output and the sounds stops.
If I select Internal Audio, the sound starts on the internal speaker again.

Comment: Are you using the latest 2016.1 of Kali? What are the problems with WiFi and sound? And this is just the Mac Mini builtin WiFi and sound?

Comment: Are they showing up in `lspci` and `lsusb`?

Comment: I have edited the question with the informations you requested.

Answer (score 1):

Kali is designed for Penetration Testing and Hacking. So, there will be far more tools available by default on Kali with regard to penetration testing. That said, I'm sure every tool included with Kali *can* run on Gentoo. However, they might not all be in the official Portage tree.

As far as your WiFi and sound not working, try following [these instructions](http://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-hard-disk-install-on-mac) and make sure you didn't miss anything. [This guide](https://wiki.debian.org/MacBook/Wireless) for troubleshooting Mac WiFi for Debian may be of use as well.

As mentioned [@dervish](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/85876/dervishe) in the comments, there is also a Gentoo Linux distribution for Penetration Testing similar to Kali (but based on Gentoo). It's called [Pentoo](http://www.pentoo.ch/).

Comment: Unfortunately the guide for troubleshooting WiFi does not explain how to resolve the issue. Maybe the instance " The b43-fwcutter utility can be used to extract firmware from a Broadcom-provided driver." could solve the problem, but I don't know how.

Comment: There's a pentest distro which is gentoo based: pentoo: http://www.pentoo.ch/